# Shopify - Enable autocomplete for search boxes with loading Icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, liquid

Hello Shopify Expert there.
Our Shopify Store have a [Auto Complete Search Script](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/enable-autocomplete-for-search-boxes) from shopify. and it's working fine. but we want to add a GIF loading icon while the user is typing in the search box. like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjEt5.png)
and here's the script

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // Current Ajax request.
  var currentAjaxRequest = null;
  // Grabbing all search forms on the page, and adding a .search-results list to each.
  var searchForms = $('form[action="/search"]').css('position','relative').each(function() {
    // Grabbing text input.
    var input = $(this).find('input[name="q"]');
    // Adding a list for showing search results.
    var offSet = input.position().top + input.innerHeight();
    $('<ul class="search-results"></ul>').css( { 'position': 'absolute','top': '54px' } ).appendTo($(this)).hide();    
    // Listening to keyup and change on the text field within these search forms.
    input.attr('autocomplete', 'off').bind('keyup change', function() {
      // What's the search term?
      var term = $(this).val();
      // What's the search form?
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      // What's the search URL?
      var searchURL = '/search?type=product&q=' + term;
      // What's the search results list?
      var resultsList = form.find('.search-results');
      // If that's a new term and it contains at least 3 characters.
      if (term.length > 3 && term != $(this).attr('data-old-term')) {
        // Saving old query.
        $(this).attr('data-old-term', term);
        // Killing any Ajax request that's currently being processed.
        if (currentAjaxRequest != null) currentAjaxRequest.abort();
        // Pulling results.
        currentAjaxRequest = $.getJSON(searchURL + '&view=json', function(data) {
          // Reset results.
          resultsList.empty();
          // If we have no results.
          if(data.results_count == 0) {
            // resultsList.html('<li><span class="title">No results.</span></li>');
            // resultsList.fadeIn(200);
            resultsList.hide();
          } else {
            // If we have results.
            $.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
              var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
              link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
              link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
              link.append('<span class="price">' + item.prices + '</span>');
              link.wrap('<li></li>');
              resultsList.append(link.parent());
              $('.search-results').css('max-height','450px');
              $('.search-results').css('overflow','auto');
            });
            // The Ajax request will return at the most 10 results.
            // If there are more than 10, let's link to the search results page.
            if(data.results_count > 10) {
              resultsList.append('<li class="all-results"><span><a href="' + searchURL + '">See all results (' + data.results_count + ')</a></span></li>');
            }
            resultsList.fadeIn(200);
          }        
        });
      }
    });
  });
  // Clicking outside makes the results disappear.
  $('body').bind('click', function(){
    $('.search-results').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

BTW, Here's our [store](https://originboardshop.com) to see live action of the auto complete search.
thank you so much !

Comment: Add a `display:none` `div` with the gif in it inside `input-outer` and as soon as the search function is triggered make it visible. And once the search is complete hide it back.

Comment: sorry , i am newbie in jquery , could you lend me some code of that ? thanks